# How can I unset svn global ignore setting?

Tags: svn, ignore

I want to unset ignore setting for a specific file in my source code.
The file is "libsomething.so".
But I haven't specified .so file as a ignore file pattern.
And I couldn't find where .so files are marked as a ignore file.

I use svn, version 1.8.15 (r1718365).

I checked /home/me/.subversion/config, /etc/subversion/config and .so is not specified as a ignore file.
I checked with "svn propedit svn:ignore .", under the directory where .svn is stored, the result was just empty file.

How can I unset this ignore setting?

Comment: `svn propdel svn:ignore .` didn't work either?

Comment: 'propdel' produces "Attempting to delete nonexistent property 'svn:ignore' on '.'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to add this specific file, you can just use

```
svn add [your_file]
```

It will add your file to be committed in next commit.

You already has listed the places of the global ignores inisde the configuration files. So I cannot give you more advice.